# mybatis exception 'There is no getter for property named (foreach item) in VO'

Tags: mybatis

I found similar exceptions but they were about collection getter.

This is my code and the exceptions is `There is no getter for property named 'variableData' in 'MyDataVO'`

Why eclipse looking a foreach item getter?

Thanks for reading

Java

```
public class MyDataVO {
    private String commonData;
    private String commonData2;
    private List<String[]> variableDataList;

    public List<String[]> getVariableDataList() {
        return variableDataList;
    }
    public void setVariableDataList(List<String[]> variableDataList){
        this.variableDataList = variableDataList;
    }
}
```

SQL

```
<insert id="insertMyData" parameterType="MyDataVO">
    INSERT INTO my_data_table (common_data, common_data2, variable_data1, variable_data2, variable_data3)
    VALUES
    <foreach collection="variableDataList" item="variableData" separator=",">
        (
            #{commonData},
            #{commonData2},
            #{variableData[0]},
            #{variableData[1]},
            #{variableData[2]}
        )
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use `<foreach>` to access the array item.

```xml
...
(
  #{commonData},
  #{commonData2},
  <foreach collection="variableData" item="str" index="idx" separator=",">
    <if test="3 > idx">
      #{str}
    </if>
  </foreach>
)
...
```

The `<if>` is unnecessary if the array always contains 3 items.